# HashMap: Match a string with a value if it contains part of the string?

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I have a text file, which is filled with many lines of code in the layout: "fiesta, ford". I read these lines with `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(...))` and then I display them in my app.

This method `findCar()` takes an input, compares it with the keys of the hashmap which are taken from the text file, and if it matches, it displays the car model and the card brand in another layout part :). What is for example: Is there a possibility to make my code a little more advanced? Let's say that the user types Fiesta 2018, or Fiesta 2019. I want it to be accepted. So I want to say that if the given string contains "Fiesta", match it with "ford" and display them. I don't know how to make it work for every other brand, and i don't want to have 100 if statements.

I am sorry for the rookie question, I have tried many many versions like `else if(car.equalsIgnoreCase(carItem.getKey())){` but I can't make it work.

```
   public String findCar(String car) {
    String x = "";
    for (HashMap.Entry<String, String> carItem: itemsMap.entrySet()) {
        if (carItem.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(car)){
        x = x + "Found " + carItem.getKey() + " in:" + carItem.getValue();
        return x;
    }
}
return "Sorry, not found :D";}
```

Comment: In your HashMap, what does the key represent? What does the value represent?

Comment: @RyanH.the key represents the model, and the value represents the company. For example when someone types micra 2019, the value of it will be nissan. So it's a HashMap<String,String>. Maybe it doesnt make sense but Im doing it for educational reasons

Comment: You're not really learning much about `HashMap` here. You're just iterating. It could be any collection at all.

Comment: @user207421 still, is there any suggestion to the question?

Answer (score 0):

You should try following code (use "contains" function and convert to one case both strings) :

```
public String findCar(String car) {

    String carLowerCase = car.toLowerCase().trim();
    String x = "";

    for (HashMap.Entry<String, String> carItem: itemsMap.entrySet()) {
        String key = carItem.getKey().toLowerCase().trim();
        if (carLowerCase.contains(key)){
           x = x + "Found " + carItem.getKey() + " in:" + carItem.getValue();
           return x;
        }
     }
     return "Sorry, not found :D";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to refine your keyword.

For example, in the

> Fiesta 2018

you only need the Fiesta part. So it makes sense say if the last four letters are digits, you simply remove it.

For example:

```
Map<String,String> modelBrand = new HashMap<>();
String keyword = "Fiesta 2018";
String[] keys = keyword.split(" [0-9]{4}");
if(keys.length > 0) {
    keyword = keys[0];
}
// Print not found since nothing in the map.
System.out.println(modelBrand.getOrDefault(keyword.toLowerCase(), "Not found"));
modelBrand.put("fiesta", "ford");
// Print ford as it finds the fiesta keyword.
System.out.println(modelBrand.getOrDefault(keyword.toLowerCase(), "Not found"));
```

A better way to do it is utilize a search engine, such as the open source solr.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I understood it :)

Comment: You are welcome! There's a concept of segmentation. That is, for a given keyword. for example the 'fiesta 2018', you could split it into 'fiesta 2018', 'fiesta 201', 'fiesta 20', 'fiesta 2', 'fiesta' , 'fiest' etc. Better do this when you put things in map, that case, the find part would be faster, just a containsKey() will do. You can do it when searching too, but it would be slower.
This is the basic concept of solr. You can leverage it.

Comment: If the user types "2018 Fiesta" this will not work. If the user can type any text for their search this solution is not robust enough.

Comment: Right! That's why you want to introduce the mechanism of solr.
Where you can say when your input is '2018 fiesta`, you can then search for all: '2018 fiesta', '018 fiesta', '2018 fiest'... 
Of course, you probably don't want all the nonsense here. Simple divide the key word into 2018, fiesta, and 18 would be fine. And for all the results, rank them.